# ASP.NET MVC. Clean way to implement persistant sorting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, paging, jquery-ui-sortable

I still haven`t found any example of sorting implementation through paging in ASP.NET MVC
(sort by name->press page 2->page 2 is still sorted by name).

I could "hack" it, make it dirty, but i`m sure there have to be good "how-to" guides for this.

What about sorting by two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep the sort expression in your model view and write it to the pagination route links.
For example like:

```
/MyEntity/Page/2?sort=Name
```

Or with custom routing like:

```
/MyEntity/Page/2/Name
```

For the latter the route mapping would look like:

```
{controller}/Page/{pageIndex}/{sortExpression}
```

Comment: If i remember correct - thing that confused me was that my views "had to know about", as i thought - database structure. You know - sort expressions kind a maps with column names. Funny. It's always nice to find out how dumb i was.

Answer (score 2):

I do it exactly the way aleris does except I use a enum field on my model for the sort values, this way it will fall back on the default if they enter a sort paremeter that doesn't exist.

```
public enum SortArticle
{
   Title,
   Published
}

public enum SortOrder
{
   Asc,
   Desc
}

articles/{sort}/{order}/{page}
articles/published/desc/1
```

Comment: These answers made me just a little bit less confused. Still can`t visualize this A-Z. I`ll try to create a small example project for myself. If that will be success, Aleris will get my "accepted answer". :)